# Unix cat function (cat * > merged.txt) in Python?

Tags: python, unix, merge, concatenation, cat

Is there a way to use the cat function from Unix in Python or something similar once a directory has been established ? I want to merge files_1-3 together into merged.txt

I would usually just find the directory in Unix and then run

```
cat * > merged.txt 

file_1.txt
file_2.txt
file_3.txt

merged.txt
```

Comment: Very related:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/16095960/748858

Comment: Also related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1001538/how-do-i-concatenate-files-in-python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we know  we are going to use "Unix" cat command (unless you are looking for a pythonic way or being performance concious)

You can use

```
import os
os.system("cd mydir;cat * > merged.txt")
```

or

as pointed by 1_CR (Thanks) and explained here
[Python: How to Redirect Output with Subprocess?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4965159/python-how-to-redirect-output-with-subprocess)

Comment: you may have a point however [check this](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#replacing-older-functions-with-the-subprocess-module)

Comment: There are a score of reasons not to just shell out; among them, the overhead of spawning a new process to spawn another new process just to read files and write them out; secondly: security, if you're using user input to determine where to read or write. Also, shelling out adds a selection of issues, like ensuring cwd is correct, $PATH, etc., and is non-portable.

Comment: Valid points. however, :) Within the context of problem raised by OP- "Is there a way to use the cat function from Unix in Python", I guess OP wants to execute simple task automation than building real application.  And I still feel this is one of the moments for which you ( say you never used, I will accept your Vote down :))  and me used "os.system" calls to execute such simple tasks by being practical.

Answer (score 4):

Use the [`fileinput`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html) module:

```
import fileinput
import glob
with open('/path/to/merged.txt', 'w') as f:
    for line in fileinput.input(glob.glob('/path/to/files/*')):
        f.write(line)
    fileinput.close()
```

Comment: how does it know which directory it is in ?

Comment: @draconisthe0ry You can pass the directory path to `glob.glob`.

Comment: IIRC, `fileinput` objects should be closed just like you close a regular file.  It wouldn't hurt to `fileinput.close()` after that for loop I think...

Comment: works, but I need a space between `content_file_1` and `content_file_2` , otherwise at least two words will merge from both files. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Use [fileinput](http://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html). Say you have a python file `merge.py` with the following code, you could call it like so `merge.py dir/*.txt`. File `merged.txt` gets written to current dir. By default, `fileinput` iterates over the list of files passed on the command line, so you can let the shell handle globbing

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import fileinput
with open('merged.txt', 'w') as f:
    for line in fileinput.input():
        f.write(line)
```