# Abbreviate the import of multiple files with loadtxt (Python)

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, import, load, concatenation

I wanna abbreviate the way I import multiples files with loadtxt, I do the next:

```
rc1    =loadtxt("20120701_Gp_xr_5m.txt", skiprows=19)
rc2    =loadtxt("20120702_Gp_xr_5m.txt", skiprows=19)
rc3    =loadtxt("20120703_Gp_xr_5m.txt", skiprows=19)
rc4    =loadtxt("20120704_Gp_xr_5m.txt", skiprows=19)
rc5    =loadtxt("20120705_Gp_xr_5m.txt", skiprows=19)
rc6    =loadtxt("20120706_Gp_xr_5m.txt", skiprows=19)
rc7    =loadtxt("20120707_Gp_xr_5m.txt", skiprows=19)
rc8    =loadtxt("20120708_Gp_xr_5m.txt", skiprows=19)
rc9    =loadtxt("20120709_Gp_xr_5m.txt", skiprows=19)
rc10   =loadtxt("20120710_Gp_xr_5m.txt", skiprows=19)
```

Then I concatenate them using:

```
GOES   =concatenate((rc1,rc2,rc3,rc4,rc5,rc6,rc7,rc8,rc9,
                     rc10),axis=0)
```

But my question is: Do I wanna reduce all of this? Maybe with a FOR or something like that. Since the files are a secuence of dates (strings).

I was thinking to do something like this

day= #### i dont know how define a string going from 01 to 31 for example

```
data="201207"+day+"_Gp_xr_5m.txt"
```

Then do this, but i think is not correct

```
GOES=loadtxt(data, skiprows=19)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you can easily get your sub-arrays with a `for`-loop, or with an equivalent list comprehension. Use the [glob module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html) to get the desired file names:

```
import numpy as np  # you probably don't need this line
from glob import glob

fnames = glob('path/to/dir')
arrays = [np.loadtxt(f, skiprows=19) for f in fnames]
final_array = np.concatenate(arrays)
```

If memory use becomes a problem, you can also [iterate over all files line by line by chaining them](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16095855/2379410) and feeding that generator to `np.loadtxt`.

---

*edit after OP's comment*

My example with `glob` wasn't very clear..

You can use "wildcards" `*` to match files, e.g. `glob('*')` to get a list of all files in the current directory. A part of the code above could therefor be written better as:

```
fnames = glob('path/to/dir/201207*_Gp_xr_5m.txt')
```

Or if your program already runs from the right directory:

```
fnames = glob('201207*_Gp_xr_5m.txt')
```

I forgot this earlier, but you should also sort the list of filenames, because the list of filenames from `glob` is not guaranteed to be sorted.

```
fnames.sort()
```

---

A slightly different approach, more in the direction of what you were thinking is the following. When variable `day` contains the day number you can put it in the filename like so:

```
daystr = str(day).zfill(2)
fname = '201207' + daystr + '_Gp_xr_5m.txt'
```

Or using a clever format specifier:

```
fname = '201207{:02}_Gp_xr_5m.txt'.format(day)
```

Or the "old" way:

```
fname = '201207%02i_Gp_xr_5m.txt' % day
```

Then simply use this in a `for`-loop:

```
arrays = []
for day in range(1, 32):
    daystr = str(day).zfill(2)
    fname = '201207' + daystr + '_Gp_xr_5m.txt'
    a = np.loadtxt(fname, skiprows=19)
    arrays.append(a)

final_array = np.concatenate(arrays)
```

Comment: Actually i didnt get to do that iteration, I read that link "iterate over all files line by line by chaining them" but i dont understand too much. I used Anaconda Python and i have all my datafiles in a folder, i set it up to run from that folder, so i think i dont need to add a path, only need a method how to do the iteration.