# Why is the context manager closed after it is yielded?

Tags: python, generator, contextmanager

I am trying to `yield` a context manager that is created in a `with` statement. However, something that I don't understand happens: the context manager is closed before it is yielded, even though the execution in the generator did not exit the scope of the `with`. For example:

```
class CM:
  def __enter__(self):
    print('enter cm')
    return self
  def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
    print('exit cm')


def make_foo():
  with CM() as cm:
    print('before yield')
    yield cm
  print('after yield')


print('before make_foo')
foo = next(make_foo())
print('after make_foo')
```

outputs

```
before make_foo
enter cm
before yield
exit cm
after make_foo
```

I saw [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41881731/is-it-safe-to-combine-with-and-yield-in-python) on a related topic, and the answer is about time when the object is garbage collected -- however why would `cm` be garbage collected before it is returned to be used by the caller here?

EDIT

When writing instead

```
foo_maker = make_foo()
foo = next(foo_maker)
```

then the CM is not closed -- so it seems that the CM is indeed GC because the generator is GC. But shouldn't it left alone since it is returned and potentially used after?

Comment: the contxt manager isn't garbage collected, the generator object is, which `.close`es it, which causes the `with` statement to execute `__exit__`

Comment: And `CM` is not gc'd. Why do you think so?

Comment: You only called `next()` once, so `make_foo()` never resumed after the `yield`.  The `with` block therefore never got a chance to exit.

Comment: This is an interesting question. I'll add that there isn't any garbage collection in cpython, there is ref counting. Their diferent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is because of your method definition and how you call it.

if you instead of `foo = next(make_foo())` use this :

```
for i in make_foo():
  print('thanks I saw cm')
```

the result would be this :

```
enter cm
before yield
thanks I saw cm
exit cm
after yield
after make_foo
```